# Can't import a Go module

Tags: go, gopath, go-chi

I'm learning Go ad I'm trying to build go file:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5/middleware"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("welcome"))
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", r)
}
```

But when I build the program with the command `go build main.go`, it outputs:

```
go: github.com/go-chi/chi/@v1.5.4: missing go.sum entry; to add it:
        go mod download github.com/go-chi/chi/
```

`go.mod`:

```
module exprog

go 1.16

require github.com/go-chi/chi/ v1.5.4
```

when I execute `go mod download github.com/go-chi/chi/`, I get this error:

```
go: github.com/go-chi/chi/@v1.5.4: malformed module path "github.com/go-chi/chi/": trailing slash
```

What I should do?

Comment: don't try to build individual go files, build the package. I'm not sure how you got `go mod download github.com/go-chi/chi/`, but you should be using `go get github.com/go-chi/chi/v5`

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: You tried what exactly? Please create a [mre], because the single [go source you have](https://play.golang.org/p/z332IlxMjMe) will not produce this error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking to download this [module](https://github.com/go-chi/chi/blob/master/go.mod), You should do `go mod download github.com/go-chi/chi/v5`. The name of the module is the header in the dependency's go.mod file.

You can remove the entry from go.mod and simply do `go mod download github.com/go-chi/chi/v5`

or

You can remove the entry from go.mod, and do `go mod tidy`. Go will fill your go.mod file based on your imports. You can do `go mod download` then.

Comment: Go will automatically run `go mod tidy` for you if you initialize a module `with go mod init ....`.

Comment: The previous comment adds to the answer but it does not explain a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

It's error not in command, it's error in go.mod file. You can fix by:

```
module exprog

go 1.16

require github.com/go-chi/chi/v5 v5
```